# How to synthesize and play sounds in Python

Tags: audio, keyboard-events, synthesizer

I want to create a python program that allows me to use my computer keyboard as a piano. This means I need to receive keyboard input, and when a given key is pressed I need to synthesize a sound at a specific frequency and then play that sound. What modules should I use to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to your program - receiving keyboard inputs and when that happens, playing Audio.

The former can be tackled with this - https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/

There are several ways for the latter - https://realpython.com/playing-and-recording-sound-python/

This person has already implemented something similar - https://github.com/Zulko/Minimix

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library I wrote for that purpose - Jupylet:
https://github.com/nir/jupylet

It includes a novel framework for creating sound synthesizers in pure Python (and Numpy) and a variety of building blocks for substractive, additive, FM, and sample based synthesizers, including a colored noise generator, resonant filters, reverb effects, and more.

See here for more information:
https://jupylet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programmers_reference_guide/synthesis.html

The library includes basic demo notebook and script showing how to create a piano app using the library:
https://github.com/nir/jupylet/blob/master/examples/14-piano.ipynb